# MySQL 5.7, Ubuntu 18, AppArmor

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apparmor

Поставил на Ubuntu Workbench и пытаюсь подключится через него к базе данных.
Но что то идёт не так.

[image: AppArmor схватил и не отпускает]

Что я уже пробовал:
1. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004185293-Unable-to-start-MySQL-on-Ubuntu-AVC-apparmor-DENIED-operation-open-
2. Создавал пользователя, отличного от root.
3. Пытался подключаться через Local Socket/Pipe.

В ubuntu я новичок.
Прошу вашей помощи.

UPD: Может я глупостями занимаюсь, что с Workbench связался? Мне бы  капельку повозится с базой, а дальше ORM на django...

Answer (score 1):

тут же "русским языком" написано - нет доступа к базе или нет прав у пользователя

что пишет с консоли команда

```
> mysql -uadmin -pТУТ_ПАРОЛЬ_ВМЕСТО_РУССКИХ_БУКВ -hlocalhost -A
```

?

146% что пользователь admin в дефолтной установке mysql отсутствует. там есть пользователь root без пароля с localhost, т.е. не нужна опция с ключом -p вообще.
 Причём у Oracle и Maria немного разный подход к этому паролю. У Maria - попроще.

Comment: Ничего подобного «тут» не написано.

Comment: `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> `

Comment: Стоило упомянуть, что прежде, чем пытаться подключится я сделал вот такого пользователя)
`CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ТУТ_МОЙ_ПАРОЛЬ';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: ну то есть пресловутого admin я не с потолка взял

Comment: все забывают в grunt-е писать пароль.

 GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON \*.\* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';